# How To Execute Scripts On Background Page Of A Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extention. My manifest.json is:

```
"page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "icons/icon19.png",
        "38": "icons/icon38.jpg"
    },
    "default_popup": "options.html"
},
```

In my extension I am trying to execute scripts which attempt to run/reach on actual web page:

```
// in options.html
chrome.tabs.executescript(null,{code:"alert('hello!');"}) ;
```

But Chrome extension debugger outputs this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'executescript'
```

**I want to reflect any changes on options to content_script or actual web page immidiately.**

In page_action scope, how can I reach "chrome" object?

Comment: It realy depends on what you are doing but, but most of the time you should be able to use ContentScript http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html
It's a much better practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now try changing `executescript` to `executeScript` the capital 'S' is important.

`executeScript` and `insertCSS` are mostly used to inject a js or css file into a given tab rather than the raw code. They are used when you want to inject that code in very specific situations. In your code you don't specify an `id` for what tab to inject the code into, so it just injects it in the given context. If you use a `chrome.tabs.query` like with the message passing, you should be able to inject the code into the actual tab.

It seems that you are trying to affect some sort of change on a given tab when you change options in a popup from a `Page Action` I personally would recommend using `jQuery` to make the actual changes while using the message passing from the other question to send a message to the given tab. You could try doing it with programmatic injection of `css` or `Javascript`, but successive changes in the options might have undesirable results.

I don't know the exact details of what kinds of changes you are trying to make. If they are purely `css` then you could have one stylesheet injected into the page and just toggle a class on the things you want to change and have a class for each scenario. If you describe what you are trying to do in more detail I could give a more detailed suggestion.

Comment: I did, but it is never reaching the scope of actual web page, just running in extension sandbox.

Comment: @Digerkam I have updated my answer with some more info about `executeScript`

Comment: Think of page_action as a popup which shows extension option, what I accomplish here is reflect any option changes to actual web page directly. I solve my problems by your answers, thank you!