# Communication Between PageAction, Background Page And ContentScript In A Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As I understood there is no way to communication directly between Page Action and Cotent Script, so I do that:

In **page_action.html**:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(
    {to:"background",key:"color",val:"red"},
    function(response) {
        console.log(response) ;
    }
) ;
```

In **background.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
        if (request.to == "background") {
            console.log("Request recieved to Background") ;
            request.to = "content" ;
            chrome.extension.sendRequest(request,function(response) {
                sendResponse(response) ;
            }) ;
        }
    }
) ;
```

In **content.js**

```
(function(){
    // ...
    // Do something initial
    // ...
    // Now start to listen
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
        function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
            if (request.to == "content") {
                // Do something with request.key and request.val
                console.log("Request recieved to Content Script") ;
                sendResponse({status:'from content'}) ;
            }
        }
    ) ;
}()) ;
```

Communication between Page Action and Background works perfectly, but nothing happen between Background and Content Script. What am I missing here? How to communicate each other properly? And most of all, is there another way that let communication more directly from Page Action to Content Script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily, there is a way to communicate directly between a `Page Action` and a `Content Script` and that would be though the [`tabs.sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage) method.

You can obtain the `id` either from [`chrome.pageAction.onClicked`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#event-onClicked) or from a simple `chrome.tabs.query`.

Once you have the ID of the tab you want to send a message to, just send the message from your `Page Action` like this:

**page_action.html**

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{message:"text"}, function(response){
    //If you need a response, do stuff with it here
  });
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  //Do stuff here
  //sendResponse({message:"stuff"});
});
```

On a side note, `sendRequest` and `onRequest` have been replaced with their [`Message`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) counterparts.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! Just there is no "tabId", only "id" :)

Comment: @Digerkam That is what I get for typing it from memory. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: My pleasure. May I ask you to take a look at that question if you experimented anything like it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102282/how-to-execute-scripts-on-background-page-of-a-chrome-extension Thank you again!